# Unable to make animation in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIViewController *myViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]];

self.window.rootViewController = myViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I want to make a UIImageView to appear, play animation and disappear after that. 
I'm adding this code to my existing code but nothing is happening:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSArray *animationFrames = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:blablahblah, nil];

    imgView.animationImages = animationFrames;
    imgView.animationDuration = 1.5;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show the image, I'm not sure where your image view code is but you should have `addSubview` if it's in a view controller.

Comment: @Dustin how do you do that, then? And most important, how do I remove it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in your ViewDidLoad.

.m

animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

[UIImageimageNamed:@"chicken1.tiff"],

[UIImageimageNamed:@"chicken2.tiff"],

[UIImageimageNamed:@"chicken3.tiff"],nil];

[animationsetAnimationRepeatCount:0];

animation.animationDuration = 1;

[animation startAnimating];

.h

IBOutlet UIImageView *animation;

Comment: This might get called more than once per app launch, if a view is deallocated and then loaded later.

Comment: I have just used it that way before.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller:

```
//use the view controller's frame
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]];

NSArray *animationFrames = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:blablahblah, nil];

imgView.animationImages = animationFrames;
imgView.animationDuration = 1.5;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

[self.view addSubview:imgView]; //Add the image view to the current view
```

to remove:

```
[imgView removeFromSuperview]; //call when animation is done
```

Comment: But how about I display it only _one time per app launch_? Any ideas how to get this thing running?

Comment: Store a boolean variable somewhere (like the app delegate) that indicates whether the animation has been shown, and check for it before you run the code.

Comment: I tried this and it's not working. I have no idea why. Put it everywhere I could and still - nothing

Comment: This code should work; try logging `[self.view subviews]` and seeing if imgView shows up.